# How to check if Custom Types is set to nullable=True

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have a CustomType , how can I check if the Column was set to nullabe=True at custom type creation ?

```
 import sqlalchemy.types as types

 class MyType(types.TypeDecorator):
     impl = types.Unicode

     def process_bind_param(self, value, dialect):
         return "PREFIX:" + value

     def process_result_value(self, value, dialect): 
         return value[7:]
```

Here is a model defined that will use it:

```
class User(BaseModel):
     __tablename__ = 'user'

     mytype = Column(MyType(), nullable=True)
```

Answer (score 5):

I don't understand what you mean with *at custom Type creation*. To check whether the column is nullable goes just like this:

```
print(User.__table__.columns['mytype'].nullable)
```

To enable your custom type handle Null (None) values you could do something like this:

```
class MyType(types.TypeDecorator):       
  impl = types.Unicode

  def process_bind_param(self, value, dialect):
    return "PREFIX:" + value if value else None

  def process_result_value(self, value, dialect):
    return value[7:] if value else None
```

Comment: I need to know the name of the column before hand, that will not work for me.

Comment: The solution you gave to check if value is passed or not, but it should check whether the field is set to nullable or not.